# Pegar mais de um elemento com JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia!

Teria como eu pegar mais de um elemento com JQuery?

Por exemplo, estou fazendo assim em meu código:

```
if (!is992()) {
        $j('.filters .title--sm').click(function(){
        $j('.filters__list').slideToggle(50);
        $j('.filters__filtered').slideToggle(50);
        $j('.filters .title').toggleClass('active'); 
    });
}
```

Queria otimizar essas duas linhas:

```
$j('.filters__list').slideToggle(50);
$j('.filters__filtered').slideToggle(50);
```

Teria como eu pegar as duas classes e usar numa linhas só? Por exemplo:

```
$j('.filters__list', '.filters__filtered').slideToggle(50);
```

Assim sei que não da, mas queria saber se tem algo parecido que eu possa usar.

Obrigado!

Comment: sim, apenas a formatação que não está muito boa utilize assim: $j('.filters__list .filters__filtered').slideToggle(50);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar a virgula para concatenar seletores em CSS. Estavas perto, seria assim:

```
$j('.filters__list, .filters__filtered').slideToggle(50);
```

Caso tenhas muitas classes para juntar talvez seja melhor dar uma classe comum a todos esses elementos.

Comment: Ah, usar igual no CSS? Que falta de atenção a minha.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho exato. O jQuery aceita seletores de CSS e mais alguns específicos do jQuery

Comment: Sergio, obrigado! kkk E eu aqui ja pensando em criar array. Quando der o tempo, marco como aceita.